# Variant on: New to Xcode can't open files in c++?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, macos, sfml

Like the questioner in "New to Xcode can't open files in c++?" I'm learning Xcode and OS X (I'm using Xcode 7 on a Yosemite mac). 
I can get the code to work perfectly when I build and run it, but can't get the executable to work when I try to run it as a stand alone program.
I'm trying to translate some games I've written on a PC in C++ using SFML.
There has to be a way to save high scores and previous games within an app, but this has me stymied.
This is the sample code I used based on the previous question:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;
    string input;

    fin.open("inputFile.txt");
    if(fin.fail())
        cout << "File failed to open." << endl;
    fin >> input;
    fin.close();

    fout.open("outputFile.txt");

    fout << input;
    fout << "\n Data transferred \n";
    fout.close();
}
```

This works perfectly when I build and run it, so I've got the proper path to the desktop folder set up. (I'm putting the data files in the same folder as the executable and specifying the path in Xcode.)
No problems when I run this within Xcode, but this is the message on the terminal console when I run the executable by itself:

"…/Desktop/datafiles/Build/Products/Debug/datafiles ; exit;
…/Desktop/datafiles/Build/Products/Debug/datafiles ; exit;

File failed to open.
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
[Process completed]"

Is there another flag or path that needs to be set within Xcode for this to work?  Two other related questions: How do I access the terminal history to see what is going on?  Finally, if I set up the project as an SFML app instead of a terminal project (command line tool app), why can't I see the files within the SFML app, even though I've set the command line flag to see hidden files, and I can see other hidden files on my hard drive?  I can see the files if I open the SFML app folder in Windows, so I know they are there.

This is my first question on Stack Overflow, so apologies if this should be appended to the previous question, but this doesn't appear to be an answer to me, but is quite a different version of the original question that is not addressed in the answers.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to report the errors (see `strerror()` and `errno`).  I suspect this issue is related to the *current working directory*, which is something you need to understand.  Have a search.

Comment: Just like on Windows and most everywhere, when you use relative paths, they're relative to the current working directory (which is what you set in XCode *for running within XCode*), not the directory where the application resides or the application bundle. To open the application bundle in Finder, right-click and select "Show Package" or whatever it's called. If you use the terminal, there should be no hidden files, all should be visible with `ls`. For information on how to use files in the bundle, see `NSBundle` and `CFBundleRef`.